# How to add a PERSISTENT watcher to a znode using Java ZooKeeper API

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I want to be notified of every creation/deletion/change of a particular znode. I am able to watch for one event, but I am not sure how to re-register the watcher again. The documentation offers an `addWatch` method with `AddWatchMode`

```
public void addWatch(String basePath,
                     Watcher watcher,
                     AddWatchMode mode)
              throws KeeperException,
                     InterruptedException
```

When I execute this method like

```
zoo.addWatch("/mypath", (watchEvent) -> {
                System.out.println("From addWatch" + watchEvent);
            }, AddWatchMode.PERSISTENT);
```

I get an exception:

```
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /mypath
```

From what I understand, PERSISTENT watches will not be removed unless explicitly asked to and every time the node is created/deleted/changed the watcher will be triggered.

I'm new to Apache Zookeeper and asynchronous Java.

Answer (score 0):

When working ZK, I would highly recommend using Netflix's [Curator library](https://curator.apache.org/)

You can easily create node/path persistent watches using the [CuratorCache](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/curator-cache.html)

I've been using this library for around 10 years now, I can confirm it works as expected